# Download a File from a URL

Tags: url, windows, download

I am trying to download a file from its URL using Windows Powershell as follows

```
invoke-webrequest -uri "http://www.ead.eurocontrol.int/pamslight/pdf/4e415453/EG/C/EN/AIP/AD/EG_AD_2_EGFF_en" -outfile "c:\temp\EGFF.pdf"
```

But get the error

Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /pamslight/pdf/4e415453/EG/C/EN/AIP/AD/EG_AD_2_EGFF_en on this server

Is this a restriction from the web site? and is there a way to download the file using its URL?

Comment: Questions here are required to be about a [website under your own control](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) since there's really no way for us to ultimately know if the answers are correct. As Quentin stated, it could be any number of things, possibly because you're not using a browser so there isn't any user agent information being supplied as would normally be the case.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a restriction from the web site?

Yes.

> and is there a way to download the file using its URL?

Maybe, but we have no idea what that way is. Maybe you need to log in and get a cookie. Maybe you need to send a JWT in a header field. Maybe the website's filesystem has just marked that file as non-readable and nobody can download it.